# Como corrigir o redireccionamento para subdomínios que estão em servidores diferentes?

Tags: laravel

Eu estou trabalhado em uma api em laravel que quando acessam o a url da api pelo navegador o usuário é redireccionado para o front-end. o problema é que a url do fron-end é concatenada com a url do back-end, quebrando o link, assim: https://base-url.com.brhttps://domino.com.br

O problema iniciou quando eu alterei uma variável ambiente que armazena a url do font.

```
Route::any('/', function () {
     header('Location: ' . env('APP_FRONTEND_URL'));
     die;
});
```

Como posso corrigir isso? Será é porque ambos os projectos estão em domínios diferentes?

Answer (score 1):

O Laravel tem vários *helpers* para evitar o envio de cabeçalhos HTTP de forma manual. Para o redirecionamento você pode usar a função `redirect` (atenção ao `return`):

```
Route::any('/', function() {
    return redirect('https://exemplo.com.br');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poder utilizar o próprio Redirect no Laravel:

```
Route::redirect('/', env('APP_FRONTEND_URL'));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#redirect-routes